# Limits while calculating area with integrals

Tags: calculus

Let's derive the area of a circle of radius $R$ using integration. Here, we take a random distance $r$ from the center and take an infinitesimal increment $dr$ which gives us an infinitesimal ring.The area of that ring is $2\pi rdr$. Now we integrate these infinitesimals ring to get the exact area. The expression stands out to be $\int_{0}^{R} 2\pi rdr$.

I don't understand why we are taking the upper limit $R$. I mean we go a distance $r$ and then take an increment and calculate the ring's area. But if we take increment after reaching $R$,that makes no sense to me since we are now overcounting an extra ring outside of the circle. Please help clear my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

The extra ring that you are counting is technically an infinitesimally thin ring. So, that doesn't contribute to the area.

Mathematically, you could have said something like

> The area is
> $$\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\int_{0}^R 2\pi r dr + h\right)=\int_{0}^R 2\pi r dr$$

Could I make myself clear?

Comment: If it doesnt contribute,then why do we count that ring?

Comment: @madness that's the whole philosophy of calculus. The intuitive idea is that if we can break a quantity into infinitely many infinitesimally small quantities and sum these small quantities up, then the sum will be larger than its parts. Just imagine taking a stick and at each step, breaking each part into two different parts. The sum is still the whole stick, but each part is made smaller and smaller by every step. While the intuition is in this "sum is larger than its parts", the rigour is in using a limiting process.

Comment: @madness I would like to suggest you the book "Infinite Powers" by Steven Strogatz